# Comparison of Spring Boot, CXF over original Tomcat, Jetty

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, cxf, spring-boot

Can someone help me with advantages and disadvantages of using Spring Boot and CXF over original Tomcat/Jetty. Is it advisable to go for Spring Boot and CXF having embedded Tomcat/Jetty. Is it worth using it in Production environment. I'm building a SOA application. How does the performance compare in either of the cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how dependent you are on customizations. Spring Boot applies a certain defaults (which Spring classifies as sensible) based on what dependencies you have in your classpath. If you don't have an ugly legacy project I would go for bootsrapping your project with Spring Boot.

The features I've grown to like are that:

- it really is easier to put up a Spring-based project
- the profile-based configuration is really easy to use
- it brings me closer to achieving a certain level of Continuous Delivery, just think about it: if you have a web project, you don't have to worry about setting up a Tomcat/Jetty on your machine. You just run java -jar package.jar
- the variety of [starter POMS](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-starter-poms) opens up some nice possibilities for integrating modern technologies

Comment: so can I use it on Production with thousands of simulatneous users

Comment: The performance of the application still rests on the application itself. Spring Boot only provides automatic configuration and bootstrapping. You are still responsible for providing proper performance.

Comment: Another useful feature, which would enhance your production stack, would be to add spring-boot-actuator, which would give you the possibility to monitor your application through HTTP endpoints, JMX or remote shell. See the reference documentation on Spring Boot Actuator (http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready)